# Trouble Using jquery Ajax and a php script to retrieve data from mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am having trouble with my current web app project with displaying a simple jpg picture based on what radio button is checked using jquery ajax with a php script to communicate with mysql.

Here is my ajax.js file:

```
$('#selection').change(function() {
   var selected_value = $("input[name='kobegreat']:checked").val();

   $.ajax( {
       url: "kobegreat.php",
       data: {"name": selected_value},
       type: "GET",
       dataType: "json",

       success: function(json) {
           var $imgEl = $("img");
           if( $imgEl.length === 0) {
               $imgEl = $(document.createElement("img"));
               $imgEl.insertAfter('h3');
               $imgEl.attr("width", "300px");
               $imgEl.attr("alt", "kobepic");
           }
           $imgEl.attr('src', json["link"]);
           alert("AJAX was a success");
      },
      cache: false
  });
});
```

And my kobegreat.php file:

```
<?php


   $db_user = 'test';
   $db_pass = 'test1';       

   if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "GET") {
       $value = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "name");
   }

   try {
       $conn = new PDO('mysql: host=localhost; dbname=kobe', $db_user, $db_pass);
       $conn->setAttribute(PDO:: ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO:: ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
       $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM greatshots WHERE name = :name');
       do_search($stmt, $value);
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
      echo 'ERROR', $e->getMessage();
  }

  function do_search ($stmt, $name) {
      $stmt->execute(['name'=>$name]);

      if($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
          $return = $row;
          echo json_encode($return);
      } else {
          echo '<p>No match found</p>;
      }
  }

?>
```

HTML code I am trying to display my image to:

```
<h2>Select a Great Kobe Moment.</h2>
<form id="selection" method="get">
   <input type="radio" name="kobegreat" value="kobe1" checked/>Kobe1
   <input type="radio" name="kobegreat" value="kobe2"/>Kobe2
   <input type="radio" name="kobegreat" value="kobe3"/>Kobe3
</form>

<div id="target">
    <h3>Great Kobe Moment!</h3>
</div>
```

And finally my database is setup like so:

```
greatshots(name, link)

name         link
------       --------
kobe1        images/kobe1
kobe2        images/kobe2
kobe3        images/kobe3
```

I know that the php script is successfully grabbing the write data from the database because all that is display under the target div is this:

```
{"name":"kobe3","0":"kobe3","link":"images\/kobe3","1":"images\/kobe3"}
```

And I know that the ajax function is returning success because the alert for a successful ajax request alerts me when I select a radio button. So I'm not sure where I'm going wrong or how to fix my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$imgEl.attr('src', json["link"]);
```

should be

```
$imgEl.attr('src', data.link);
```

Comment: That was an error I had when I copied my code from sublime, suppose to be function(json), but json.link doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

You have `$imgEl.attr('src', json["link"]);` and var name in function is data, try `$imgEl.attr('src', data.link);`

Comment: That was an error I had when I copied my code from sublime, suppose to be function(json), but json.link doesn't work either.

Comment: I've run your js on local browser and looks ok, check in dev tools if images exists and you have access to them. Try to load in webrowser like http://localhost/images/kobe3 and check if they are there (maybe you are missing extension? like .png, .jpg?)

Answer (score 0):

1 . change  `$imgEl.attr('src', json["link"]);`
to  `$imgEl.attr('src', data.link);`

2 . append the image to your DOM, by putting below code after you assign source to image element(above code).

```
document.getElementById('target').appendChild($imgEl);
```

Assuming *target* to be div id where you want to display image.